# How to force RollingFile durign runtime with CronTriggeringPolicy?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

According to this link, `log4j2` can force a logfile rollover from code, since version  `2.5`.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-89

The question is: how can I force this? The `RollingFileManager` has a `public synchronized void rollover()` method, that is invoked by `CronTriggeringPolicy`.

But how could I create that policy during runtime?

Comment: Can you add more to your question? I am wondering why you can't just configure the CronTriiggeringPolicy.  I am also not sure what being able to call the rollover method has to do with this.

Comment: Well I just don't know how I can configure the policy at will programmatically within the running code. I want to use this to force and trigger a rollover at custom dynamic times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the RollingFileManager with the CronTriggeringPolicy - or any other policies you want.

To force a rollover programmatically, assuming you have configured a RollingFile Appender with the name "RollingFile" you would do:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;

LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
Appender app = lc.getAppender("RollingFile");
if (app instanceof RollingFileAppender) {
    ((RollingFileAppender)app).getManager().rollover();
}
```

The CronTriggeringPolicy isn't really designed to have the schedule updated dynamically.

Comment: Thanks. What's the different between `getContext(false/true)`?

Comment: In http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html there is a discussion about ContextSelectors. Some of them use a ThreadLocal as a quick way to locate the LoggerContext.  ClassLoaderContextSelector can support the ThreadLocal but normally it isn't used. If you set the value to true then ClassLoaderContextSelector will only look for the LoggerContext in the ThreadLocal, which isn't what you usually want and may return the incorrect LoggerContext. Setting it to false will cause it to locate the LoggerContext associated with the ClassLoader.